# Firebase Cloud Function triggered by a Table datetime field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a question regarding the triggering of Cloud Functions in Firebase.

I've seen the ones triggered by Creating, Delete or Update in Firestore, but what about if I have a Collection in Firestore in which documents have a Specific Date Time Field, and when that date comes the Function can auto-trigger.

Like if in the Collection Games, I have a Document in which the Date field is April 20, 2022, 18:30:00 UTC when that time comes a function will auto-trigger and run.

Is this possible to do, and if it is can someone show me a tutorial or something?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup a scheduler.

Eg. Every minute your function starts and queries Firestore for documents with `your_date_field` value in the past.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: You would easily eat your budget if you trigger a function every minute instead of triggering only when the event starts